# Split directory path powershell

Tags: powershell, split, directory

I want to split directory path using power shell. My full path is D:\data\path1\path2\abc.txt and i want to split it to path2\abc.txt. 
Can someone let me know how can I do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
$last2parts = "D:\data\path1\path2\abc.txt".Split("\") | Select-Object -Last 2
$last2parts -join "\"
```

In reply to your comment on another solution try this. Just remove your constant d:\data\path1.  Then perform the split

```
$last2parts = "D:\data\path1\path2\abc.txt".Replace("D:\data\path1","") 
$last2parts =$last2parts.Split("\") | Select-Object -Last 2
$last2parts -join "\"
```

Or try perhaps this if you want everything after D:\data\path1

```
$lastparts = "D:\data\path1\path2\abc.txt".Replace("D:\data\path1","") 
$lastparts =$lastparts.Split("\") 
$lastparts -join "\"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ChiliYago. that helps :)

Comment: Kindly mark my answer as solved for you. Glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

```
$PathAsString = "D:\data\path1\path2\abc.txt"

[System.IO.Path]::Combine($(Split-Path -leaf $(Split-Path $PathAsString)),$(Split-Path -leaf $PathAsString))
```

Uses the system's delimiter rather than specifying Windows' '\' character.
Honestly if I knew this was only ever going to run on Windows systems I'd go with @ChiliYago's answer since you can't put the path delimiter character in a file or directory name like you can in Linux.

Comment: Thanks Guys and apologize for not asking right question a first attempt. I have multiple such file path where part "D:\data\path1\" will remain constant and second part will keep changing as below :           D:\data\path1\path2\a.txt 
D:\data\path1\path3\path4\b.txt                                                       
Finding a way where I can remove first part and get second part as output. I tried                                                                              $last2parts = "D:\data\path1\path2\abc.txt".Split("\") | Select-Object -Last 2 but it wont help in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the super late post! I think you may have got the fix. But here is something you can try.

You can try using the substring() function as well.

```
$fullPath = "D:\data\path1\path2\abc.txt"
$rootPath = "D:\data\path1\"
$filePath = $fullPath.substring($rootPath.length, ($fullPath.length - $rootPath.length) )
```

Something like this may help you.